# How to show the pipe "|" symbol in Markdown table?

Tags: markdown

I want to show a markdown table where one of cells has a pipe "|"

```
Column1 | Column2
------- | -------
  |     | hello
```

Just doesn't work. How to escape the | in a table? I tried *|* also didn't work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on your markdown interpreter. But in general markdown escapes with [backslash](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) (like [markdown extra additional the pipe](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#backslash))

```
Column1 | Column2
------- | -------
 \|     | hello
```

This works in markdown:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| | | hello |

Answer (score 12):

You can use the HTML Entity

```
Column1 | Column2
------- | -------
&#x7c;  | hello
```

[Unicode Character VERTICAL LINE](http://fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/7c)