# How can I write pipelines (|) inside tables in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'd like to documentate my code using the simbol |(pipeline) inside a table. Is is possible in markdown without breaking the table structure?

Something like this:

```
| Text | Text | Text |
| :---: | :---: | :---: |
| || | some text here | blablabla |
```

As you can see below, the pipelines break the table in markdown, once it is used to demarcate the content inside the table. I'm trying to find a way of writing the pipelines in some formatting without breaking the table content:
| Text | Text | Text |
| :---: | :---: | :---: |
| || | some text here | blablabla |

I've already tried some of the basic formatting, like:

````
`||`
```||```
*||*
**||**
***||***
<html>||</html>
<table struct in html>
````

And many others...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show the pipe "|" symbol in Markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723396/how-to-show-the-pipe-symbol-in-markdown-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape that character by using a backslash: `\|`

Alternatively you can use the HTML entity `&#124;`